# R trying to write a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I'm trying to write a table from R into SQL using RODBC.

A very simple example of what am I doing

```
ch <- odbcConnect("a.server")
tab <- data.frame(c("a", "b"), c(1, 2)); colnames(tab) <- c("col1", "col2")
sqlSave(ch,tab,db.name)
```

and I'm getting the following error

> Error in sqlColumns(channel, tablename) :    ‘ICOMModelos.dbo.tabla’:
>   table not found on channel

I already tried to convert the columns to factor or character and I'm getting the same error. I also tried to drop the table before `sqlSave` and the same error :(

Comment: Is the value of `db.name` `'ICOMModelos.dbo.tabla'`?

Comment: exactly, the name of the table